# How to hide OptionMenu in Activty when showing OptionMenu from Fragment

Tags: android

I use `OptionMenu` in my `Activity`, and I use another `OptionMenu` in my `Fragment's`.

When I show `Fragment` with `optionMenu` I see both `optionsMenu` - from `Activity` and `Fragment`.

How to hide `optionMenu` from `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```